# Automated crop row detection

Tags: qgis, agriculture

I'm trying to identify crop row automatically (or as automated as possible). So far I can identify lines using supervised classification in QGIS (semiclassificationplugin) or Ecognition, I successfully extract the polygons but I can not turn the polygons into a single continuous line .

What I have:
[image: What i have]

What I want:
[image: what i want]

Today I saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwIDbXHS8nY. In the video, the software identifies the sugar cane and transforms into dots, then in a line connecting all the dots.

[image: the way i want it]

This software does what it's trying to do. I would like to know how this is done.

Comment: Have you read https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons-in-qgis

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the QGIS Plugin available from the following link: https://github.com/AndresHerrera/croprows_generator_pa_v2