# How to make a Heat Map of Distance between a set of parallel lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, distance, heat-map, parallel-lines

How to make a Heat Map of Distance between a set of parallel lines in QGIS?

This question is an extension of Question posted on the following link: [Distance between multiple parallel lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287265/distance-between-multiple-parallel-lines)

I have a set of parallel lines (as in the image below), I am seeking to find the minimum distance of each line and create a heat map to visualize the distribution of distance between closest neighbors within extent of the layer in the direction of orientation of the lines.

[image]

Shapefile of the set of parallel lines is available from the following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F8ZF6pZXB6RlqiASJ8m6J1f-LM9yEn4Z?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

1. Add additional vertices to your lines using `Densify by count`.
2. Extract vertices from the densified line.
3. Apply heatmap symbol renderer to the extracted vertices.

*Screenshot: original lines are extended to see their distance and compare it with the rendered heatmap:*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native QGIS `Line Density` algorithm for this task. It computes a density value based on line segments in a search radius as you can see in the picture.

[image]

You find the algorithm in the QGIS processing toolbox in the interpolation algorithm group.