# Opening old QGIS model in current QGIS versions

Tags: qgis, convert, qgis-modeler, modelling

There is an older answer by @underdark to this post: [Finding centrelines from polygons in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/175152/88814)
She [links a QGIS model](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anitagraser/QGIS-Processing-tools/master/2.12/models/polygon_to_centerline.model) that apparently was created in QGIS 2.12. It has the file extension `.model`

When I try to open the model in QGIS 3.16, it appears that only models in the new `.model3` file extension can be opened. Other models do not appear in the opening dialog and thus can't be selected. I tried to simply change the file extension, but that did not work. When trying to open it, I get an error: `model could not be loaded`.

Is there a way to convert the model to run it in newer QGIS versions?

Comment: Have you tried to simply change the extension? If so, what happens when you try to run the model?

Comment: Yes, that's first thing I tried, it did not work.

Comment: Then you probably have to recreate the model - and you could add it to that question, or edit @underdark's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Processing in QGIS 3 was refactored a lot and many algorithms were
> changed. So it is not possible to covert old models into new format.
> You need to recreate it.

says Alexander Bruy, QGIS contributor, core developer and translation team lead, in [this post](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/model-built-in-QGIS2-to-be-imported-in-QGIS3-td5364681.html).