# Can I convert a QGIS xxx.model to xxx.model3?

Tags: qgis, model

I have a number of old QGIS processing models (xxx.model from 2015) that I want to update to xxx.model3. Is this possible? Cheers

Comment: No, never heard about a tool to convert QGIS2 models to QGIS3 models

Answer (score 0):

Found same answer in a previous question - seems like models need to be re-built.

[Opening old QGIS model in current QGIS versions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384299/opening-old-qgis-model-in-current-qgis-versions).

Damn!