# Calculating the line with which the buffer was created

Tags: qgis, line, buffer

My problem is that I have a buffer with a 800m diameter but need to have a 1km diameter.

I don't have the line-feature on which the buffer was created ... so I want to recreate the line by doing the buffer-calculation the other way round. I haven't found sth yet so I thought someone might had a similar issue in the past and knows how to create the line with which my buffer was created or has an other solution. I was trying to Buffer the Buffer by adding 100m but that is not possible.

Comment: Just buffer the buffer by another 100m. Can you explain why it is not possible?

Comment: Cause I'm an idiot.
The data was in KML and I just imported it into my project. Then I merged the different buffer layers and stopped thinking. I had to safe the merged buffers (and dissolve them) as an ESRI Shape with a matching coordinate system and now it works.

Anysways I'm still wondering, if it is possible to do the buffer-calculation the other way round?

And thanks for responding so quickly!

Comment: In theory the reverse operation is rather trivial. In practice it is a little convoluted if you have to work with higher-level functionality.

Comment: Can something like this work? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons-in-qgis

Comment: Yes, that can work :) Thanks for that.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the buffers